# Laravel Database query returns empty collection

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have a small table and try to use some filters to get some specific data out of it.

My attempt:

```
$matchingCars = Car::where([
    ['brand', '=', request('brand')],
    ['model', '=', request('model')],
    ['price', '<', request('maxPrice')],
])->get();
```

Result:

```
Collection {#249 ▼
  #items: []
}
```

You can see nothing is returned. However, if I do the queries one by one and count the result, then I get a number higher than 0, so there are models who pass my filters!

```
    $checkBrands = Car::where('brand', '=', request('brand'))->get(); 
    $checkModels = Car::where('model', '=', request('model'))->get(); 
    $checkPrice  = Car::where('price', '<', request('maxPrice'))->get(); 

    echo count($checkBrands) . "<br>";   //output: 1
    echo count($checkModels). "<br>";    //output: 1
    echo count($checkPrice). "<br>";     //output: 8
    die;
```

Why are they not stored in the collection?

Comment: Just because each individual one has results doesn't mean their intersection does. Use `orWhere` to be sure that's the problem. If you get 10 results that means the intersection is empty.

Comment: Oh, thats true, thanks for the hint!

Comment: Yes the problem was indeed because the car with correct Brand and correct Model was much more expensive then my max price, so thats why the collection was empty..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to `orWhere()`:-

```
$matchingCars = Car::where('brand', '=', request('brand'))
                   ->orwhere('model', '=', request('model'))
                   ->orwhere('price', '<', request('maxPrice'))->get()
```

Note:-

you said:- `However, if I do the queries one by one and count the result, then I get a number higher than 0`

But this doesn't mean that combination of all these three queries with `AND` will return result.

So apply `OR` condition like above.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$matchingCars = Car::where('brand', '=', request('brand'))
    ->where('model', '=', request('model'))
    ->where('price', '<', request('maxPrice'))->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$matchingCars = Car::where('brand', '=', request('brand'))
                   ->where('model', '=', request('model'))
                   ->where('price', '<', request('maxPrice'))->get();
```

And make sure that that you have the right things returned by `request()`

Comment: Where is the difference between your answer and the answer of @Paras?

Comment: I believe not, but you can see it as a confirmation of his answer. He was just faster. :)